# Having trouble with MPI_Reduce

Tags: c, mpi

It's my first post on the website, I've been reading through it for years, and it always helped me fix my code.

Currently, I am trying to create an MPI program that splits the MPI_WORLD_COMM into two equal parts (comm1 and comm2).

Within comm1, I split a vector among all the processes using MPI_Scatter(), computing the mean for each process, and using MPI_Reduce() to compute the entire mean.

Afterwards, using MPI_Bcast(), I send the computed mean to all processes within MPI_WORLD_COMM.

Within comm2, I split the same vector among all the processes using MPI_Scatter(), computing the variance for each process, and using MPI_Reduce() to compute the entire variance.

The master process for each communicator displays the calculated values.

---

My issue is currently that each process computes its mean successfully, but MPI_Reduce() ignores the value from the first process. Same thing goes with the `variance.`

I also get some segfaults, which I think are related to my error.

---

My code (I hand-fixed the mean when computing the variance to make sure the same 'error' happens):

```c
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <time.h>
    
    #include <mpi.h>
    
    #define N 100
    
    
    double compute_mean (double* v, int count);
    double compute_var  (double *v, double mean, int count);
    
    
    int main (int argc, char **argv)
    {
      MPI_Comm comm1, comm2;
      MPI_Group world_group, group1, group2;    
      int i, my_rank, new_rank = -1, nproc;
      
      double mean, sigma, local_sum,*data,*local_data;  
    
      int *ranks1, *ranks2;
      
    
      MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
      MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&nproc);
      MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);
      
    
      MPI_Comm_group(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_group);
    
      ranks1 = (int*) malloc ((nproc/2)*sizeof(int));
      ranks2 = (int*) malloc ((nproc/2)*sizeof(int));
      
      for(i = 0; i < nproc/2; i++)
      {
          ranks1[i] = i;
          ranks2[i] = nproc/2 + i;
      }
    
      MPI_Group_incl(world_group, nproc/2, ranks1, &group1);
      MPI_Group_incl(world_group, nproc/2, ranks2, &group2);
        
      MPI_Comm_create(MPI_COMM_WORLD, group1, &comm1);
      MPI_Comm_create(MPI_COMM_WORLD, group2, &comm2);
    
      if(comm1 != MPI_COMM_NULL)
        MPI_Comm_rank(comm1, &new_rank);
      if(comm2 != MPI_COMM_NULL)
        MPI_Comm_rank(comm2, &new_rank);
    
    
    if(new_rank == 0)
    {
        printf("Reading file - process %d\n", my_rank);
        data = (double*) malloc (N * sizeof(double));
        FILE *f = fopen("input_vec.dat","r");
        for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
          fscanf(f, "%lf\n", &data[i]);
        }
        fclose(f);
        free(f);
    }
    
    local_data = (double*) malloc ((N/(nproc/2))*sizeof(double));
    local_sum = 0;
    mean = 0;
      
    if(comm1 != MPI_COMM_NULL){
      MPI_Scatter(data,N/(nproc/2),MPI_DOUBLE,local_data,N/(nproc/2),MPI_DOUBLE,0,comm1);
    }
    if(comm2 != MPI_COMM_NULL){
      MPI_Scatter(data,N/(nproc/2),MPI_DOUBLE,local_data,N/(nproc/2),MPI_DOUBLE,0,comm2);
    }
    
     if(comm1 != MPI_COMM_NULL)
     {
       local_sum = compute_mean(local_data,N/(nproc/2));
       printf("(comm1) - Local mean for process %d is: %f\n", new_rank, local_sum);
       MPI_Reduce(&local_sum, &mean, nproc/2, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_SUM, 0, comm1);
     }
    
    MPI_Bcast(&mean,1,MPI_DOUBLE,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    
    if(comm1 != MPI_COMM_NULL && new_rank == 0)
    {
      printf("(comm1) - The mean is: %f\n",mean);
    }
      
    
    if(comm2 != MPI_COMM_NULL)
    {
      local_sum = compute_var(local_data, 0.091529, N/(nproc/2));
      printf("(comm2) - Local variance for process %d is: %f\n", new_rank, local_sum);
      MPI_Reduce(&local_sum,&sigma,nproc/2,MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_SUM, 0, comm2);
    }
    
    
    if(comm2 != MPI_COMM_NULL && new_rank == 0)
    {
      printf("(comm2) - The variance is: %f\n", sigma);
    }
    
    
    free(ranks1);
    free(ranks2);
    if (new_rank == 0) free(data);
    free(local_data);
    //MPI_Comm_free(&comm1);
    //MPI_Comm_free(&comm2);
    
      MPI_Finalize();
      return 0;
    }
    
    double compute_mean(double* v, int count)
    {
      int i;
      double total  = 0;
      for(i = 0; i < count; i++)
        total += v[i];
      total /= N;
      return total;
    }
    
    double compute_var(double* v, double mean, int count)
    {
      int i;
      double total = 0;
      for(i = 0; i < count; i++){
        double diff = v[i] - mean;
        total += diff*diff;
      }
      total /= N-1;
      return total;
    }
```

---

The output (rearranged so it's easier to see - I don't think it matters?) :

```
Reading file - process 0
(comm1) - Local mean for process 0 is: 0.019051
(comm1) - Local mean for process 1 is: 0.021419
(comm1) - Local mean for process 2 is: 0.024029
(comm1) - Local mean for process 3 is: 0.027030
(comm1) - The mean is: 0.072478                         (EDIT ---> correct is 0.091529)

Reading file - process 4
(comm2) - Local variance for process 0 is: 0.000061
(comm2) - Local variance for process 1 is: 0.000011
(comm2) - Local variance for process 2 is: 0.000008
(comm2) - Local variance for process 3 is: 0.000073
(comm2) - The variance is: 0.000092                     (EDIT ---> correct is 0.000153)

[DESKTOP-FVPJMLQ:02619] *** Process received signal ***
[DESKTOP-FVPJMLQ:02619] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[DESKTOP-FVPJMLQ:02619] Signal code:  (128)
[DESKTOP-FVPJMLQ:02619] Failing at address: (nil)
[DESKTOP-FVPJMLQ:02629] *** Process received signal ***
[DESKTOP-FVPJMLQ:02629] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[DESKTOP-FVPJMLQ:02629] Signal code:  (128)
[DESKTOP-FVPJMLQ:02629] Failing at address: (nil)
[DESKTOP-FVPJMLQ:02619] [ 0] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x3ef20)[0x7ffe1ad3ef20]
[DESKTOP-FVPJMLQ:02619] [ 1] [DESKTOP-FVPJMLQ:02629] [ 0] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x3ef20)[0x7fceea13ef20]
[DESKTOP-FVPJMLQ:02629] [ 1] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x3d)/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x3d)[0x7ffe1ad9798d]
[DESKTOP-FVPJMLQ:02619] [ 2] ex2(+0x1309)[0x7ffe1b801309]
[DESKTOP-FVPJMLQ:02619] [ 3] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe7)[0x7ffe1ad21b97]
[DESKTOP-FVPJMLQ:02619] [ 4] ex2(+0xc5a)[0x7ffe1b800c5a]
[DESKTOP-FVPJMLQ:02619] *** End of error message ***
[0x7fceea19798d]
[DESKTOP-FVPJMLQ:02629] [ 2] ex2(+0x12ea)[0x7fceeae012ea]
[DESKTOP-FVPJMLQ:02629] [ 3] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe7)[0x7fceea121b97]
[DESKTOP-FVPJMLQ:02629] [ 4] ex2(+0xc5a)[0x7fceeae00c5a]
[DESKTOP-FVPJMLQ:02629] *** End of error message ***
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun noticed that process rank 0 with PID 0 on node DESKTOP-FVPJMLQ exited on signal 11 (Segmentation fault).
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
[DESKTOP-FVPJMLQ:02614] 7 more processes have sent help message help-btl-vader.txt / cma-permission-denied
[DESKTOP-FVPJMLQ:02614] Set MCA parameter "orte_base_help_aggregate" to 0 to see all help / error messages
```

Using a serial program, the correct output would be:

```
Mean: 0.091529
Variance: 0.000153
```

For completeness, I will attach the file [input_vec.dat](https://pastebin.com/RsjrR3cM)

---

As you can see, it fails me both at the mean and at the variance, and I really don't know why.

Comment: the `count` argument of `MPI_Reduce()` should be `1`

Comment: Thank you, I didn't catch that! I can't believe that was the only thing... staring at the code for hours, I'm a bit embarrassed. Code blindness at its finest.

Comment: everyone needs an extra pair of eyes once in a while, take it easy! and feel free to remove this question since that was a typo-like kind of question.